# org.apache.aries.jpa:org.apache.aries.jpa.blueprint:2.3.0 - Can't make run

Tags: hibernate, jpa, osgi, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi

I'm following the tutorial here (https://github.com/apache/aries-jpa/tree/master/examples) to run the aries-jpa examples, but unsuccessfully. The README.md file says to performa the following operations:

```
feature:repo-add mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc-features/0.8.0/xml/features
feature:install scr transaction pax-jdbc-config pax-jdbc-h2 pax-jdbc-pool-dbcp2 http-whiteboard jpa hibernate/4.3.6.Final
```

The last command displays the following error message~:~

```
Error executing command: No matching features for hibernate/[4.3.6.Final,4.3.6.Final]
```

So I'm doing just:

```
feature:install scr transaction pax-jdbc-config pax-jdbc-h2 pax-jdbc-pool-dbcp2 http-whiteboard jpa hibernate
```

and this works. Looking at the installed features I have:

```
karaf@root()> feature:list | grep hibernate
hibernate-orm                            │ 5.1.13.Final-redhat-1           │          │ Started     │ hibernate-osgi                                │ Combines all Hibernate core dependencies and requ
hibernate-envers                         │ 5.1.13.Final-redhat-1           │          │ Uninstalled │ hibernate-osgi                                │ Feature for easily adding Envers support to hiber
hibernate-infinispan                     │ 5.1.13.Final-redhat-1           │          │ Uninstalled │ hibernate-osgi                                │ Feature for easily adding Infinispan-based cachin
hibernate-ehcache                        │ 5.1.13.Final-redhat-1           │          │ Uninstalled │ hibernate-osgi                                │
hibernate-validator                      │ 5.3.5.Final-redhat-2            │          │ Uninstalled │ hibernate-validator-osgi-features             │
hibernate-validator-paranamer            │ 5.3.5.Final-redhat-2            │          │ Uninstalled │ hibernate-validator-osgi-features             │
hibernate                                │ 5.1.13.Final-redhat-1           │ x        │ Started     │ enterprise-4.2.0.fuse-710024-redhat-00002     │ Hibernate JPA engine support
karaf@root()>
```

After that, the document instructs to do that:

```
install -s mvn:org.apache.aries.jpa/org.apache.aries.jpa.blueprint/2.3.0
install -s mvn:org.apache.aries.jpa.example/org.apache.aries.jpa.example.tasklist.model/2.3.0
install -s mvn:org.apache.aries.jpa.example/org.apache.aries.jpa.example.tasklist.blueprint/2.3.0
```

This works as expected but, when I go to http://localhost:8181/tasklist I get the following in the log:

```
15:16:06.199 ERROR [Blueprint Extender: 3] Unable to start blueprint container for bundle org.apache.aries.jpa.example.tasklist.blueprint/2.3.0 due to unresolved dependencies [(&(osgi.unit.name=tasklist)(objectClass=javax.persistence.EntityManager))]
```

Since this is the official sample supposed to prove that the whole stuff is working I would expect it to work as it is, without doing any particular thing. But for some reasons it doesn't. I have seen this issues reported several times but no solution. Please help.

Oh, and **the version I'm using is 4.2.0.fuse-710024-redhat-00002**

Kind regards,

Nicolas

Comment: Did you understand that, what I'm talking about here is a tutorial and, consequently, one doesn't have anything else to do them follow the given instructions ?

Comment: We probably have different ideas of what "help" means. Any body is able to read an exception and to say what it means. You're comment explains what the exception means, which any body knows and I didn't wait for you to explain that. My question was why an official tutorial supposed to guide people raises exceptions ? Is that because I didn't follow correctly the instructions ? Is that because the tutorial itself is not complete ? You seem to think that the tutorial is missing steps. This is highly unprobable but, should you think that, please feel free to add to it the missing steps.

Comment: I think the tutorial was written for a different karaf version. I will try and give you feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I updated the example to the versions used in karaf 4.2.1. The closure based example works now. The blueprint based example gives an exception.

I opened an issue at the apache aries jira to track this. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARIES-1869

We solved the issue. The reason was a bug in the blueprint core bundle. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARIES-1793 . Apache karaf 4.2.2 will include this fix.